# F# and dotNetOpenAuth

Tags: asp.net-mvc, f#, dotnetopenauth

Has anyone gotten dotNetOpenAuth to work with F# and ASP.NET MVC yet?

I've corrected error after error, and keep getting more and more obscure errors; I'm just wondering if I'm chasing a bottomless rabbit hole.

Comment: I keep running into things like references not being found, NullReferences, mismatches between versions; fixed all of that, and got OutOfMemory exceptions, fixed that and ended up with a an ArgumentOutOfRange exception on response.

Comment: I assume all these fixes were in your own code?  I wouldn't expect DotNetOpenAuth to present any problems to F# in particular.  Is your main source of problems that there aren't any F# samples for you to start from?

Comment: I guess, I went off a few examples to even get F# working with ASP.NET MVC 4, my knowledge of F# isn't as high as it is of C#. But all of the above issues have been fixed; at this point, I have the problem that a redirecting response (like I get from using Google's openID) returns a 404; but the exact same code on C# returns my View.

Comment: If you can include logs (http://tinyurl.com/dnoalogs) of the C# and F# prototypes you have in your question, we can review them and perhaps understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I have got it to work.

I don't remember having many problems. For the UI side of things I used the jquery plugin "openid-jquery.js", as used by stackoverflow for their login, and just used dotneopenauth to do the server side processing.